# flutter can't recognize list atributes in listview builder

Tags: flutter, listview, builder

I want to make a list that shows some different kebab stores. I created a list with all the attributes i needed but flutter cant recognize or display the attribute "name" or any other attribute in the Listview builder and

I can't figure out why I appreciate every helpful command.

the error:

> The getter 'image' isn't defined for the type 'List Doener'.

and this Doenerscrollliste class is inside a body container.

```
class DoenerScrollListe extends StatefulWidget {
  const DoenerScrollListe({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DoenerScrollListe> createState() => _DoenerScrollListeState();
}

class _DoenerScrollListeState extends State<DoenerScrollListe> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  int initialPage = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: Doener_all.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        height: 120,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.orange[400],
            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(Doener_all.image))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my model file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Doener {
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final String ratingImage;
  final String price;
  final String describtion;

  Doener({
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.ratingImage,
    required this.price,
    required this.describtion,
  });
}

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
List<Doener> Doener_all = [
  Doener(
      name: "Rüyam",
      image: "assets/images/Ryam.jpg",
      ratingImage: "dsd",
      price: "4,10",
      describtion: "Sehr guter Döner Top Preis Leistung"),
  Doener(
    name: "Pamfeliya",
    image: "assets/images/Pamfilya.jpg",
    ratingImage: "asdaa",
    price: "4,10",
    describtion: "Bestes Fleisch",
  ),
  Doener(
      name: "K'Ups",
      image: "assets/images/KUps.jpg",
      ratingImage: "sdsd",
      price: "4,10",
      describtion: "Guter Döner"),
];
```

Comment: are you using multi/nested scrollable widget? not sure what are doing with `_pageController` and you can avoid using `shrinkWrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You like to get specific image in this case,
replace

```dart
AssetImage(Doener_all.image)
```

with

```dart
AssetImage(Doener_all[index].image))
```

More about [`List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: worked perfect now thanks :)